# Any alternatives to emacs-w3m for html, decoding, etc?

Tags: emacs

Based upon what I have read on the internet, it appears that emacs-w3m will not work with a current version of Emacs (e.g., 24.3 or pre-24.4 developer build).  The error message relates to `wrong-type-argument arrayp nil` and `w3m-ems`.  I'm using Wanderlust and would like to decode html e-mail automatically and so forth.

Thanks.

It looks like the first problem relates to `wrong-type-argument cclp w3m-euc-japan-decoder`, which is not a part of `w3m-ems.el`.  I'll add more if I find anything else . . .

Here is the error message when typing M-x w3m:

```
Debugger entered−−Lisp error: (wrong−type−argument arrayp nil)

byte−code("\305\306\307\310!\203\f^@\311\202^M^@\312\"\210\313\314\315\316E\317\313\314\315\320
\211^X\300N)\321HE\322\313\314\315\323\211^X\300N)\321HE\324\313\314\315\325\211^X\300N)\321HE\32
6\307\327!\203F^@\330\202G^@\331FFFF\332B^Y\333\334N\203{^@\335\336\337\340\341\342\343\n\344 ^K$
BDDE!\210\335\336\345\340\341\342\343\f\346 ^K$BDDE!\210\202\235^@\335\336\337\340\341\342\343\n
^K#BDDE!\210\335\336\345\340\341\342\343\f ^K#BDDE!\210)\305\207" [charset source w3m−cc
l−write−euc−japan−character w3m−ccl−generate−ncr w3m−ccl−write−iso−latin−1−character defalias w3m
−make−ccl−coding−system fboundp define−coding−system (lambda (coding−system mnemonic docstring de
coder encoder) "Define a new CODING−SYSTEM by CCL programs DECODER and ENCODER.\nCODING−SYSTEM, D
ECODER and ENCODER must be symbols.\nThis function is an interface to ‘define−coding−system’." (d
efine−coding−system coding−system docstring :mnemonic mnemonic :coding−type (quote ccl) :ccl−deco
der decoder :ccl−encoder encoder)) #[(coding−system mnemonic docstring decoder encoder) "\305^H\3
06 \n^K\fB%\207" [coding−system mnemonic docstring decoder encoder make−coding−system 4] 7 "Def
ine a new CODING−SYSTEM by CCL programs DECODER and ENCODER.\nCODING−SYSTEM, DECODER and ENCODER
must be symbols.\nThis function is an interface to ‘make−coding−system’."] if r1 == 129 ((r1 = (r
0 + 128))) mule−unicode−0100−24ff 0 ((r1 = ((((r0 & 16256) >> 7) − 32) * 96)) (r0 &= 127) (r1 +=
(r0 + 224))) mule−unicode−2500−33ff ((r1 = ((((r0 & 16256) >> 7) − 32) * 96)) (r0 &= 127) (r1 +=
(r0 + 9440))) mule−unicode−e000−ffff ((r1 = ((((r0 & 16256) >> 7) − 32) * 96)) (r0 &= 127) (r1 +=
(r0 + 57312))) ccl−compile−lookup−character ((lookup−character utf−subst−table−for−encode r1 r0)
(if (r7 == 0) (r1 = 65533))) ((r1 = 65533)) ((if (r1 == 65533) (write−repeat 126) (r0 = r1))) ut
f−translation−table−for−encode translation−table−id eval define−ccl−program w3m−euc−japan−encoder
quote 4 loop append ((translate−character utf−translation−table−for−encode r1 r0)) w3m−iso−latin
−1−encoder ((translate−character utf−translation−table−for−encode r1 r0))] 15)
require(w3m−ems)
byte−code("\302\303!\210\302\304!\210^H\305Y\203^U^@\302\306!\210\202#^@\307\310\311\312\313\31
4 \315\"!\316#\"\210^H\317W\204−^@\302\320!\210\302\321!\210\302\322!\210\302\323!\210\302\3
24\325\326#\207" [emacs−major−version emacs−version require w3m−util w3m−proc 21 w3m−ems error "E
macs−w3m of this version no longer supports Emacs %s" mapconcat identity nbutlast split−string "\
\." "." 23 bookmark−w3m w3m−fb w3m−hist timezone image−mode nil t] 8)
autoload−do−load((autoload "w3m" "Visit World Wide Web pages using the external w3m command.\n\
nWhen you invoke this command interactively for the first time, it will\nvisit a page which is po
inted to by a string like url around the\ncursor position or the home page specified by the ‘w3m−
home−page’\nvariable, but you will be prompted for a URL if ‘w3m−quick−start’ is\nnil (default t)
or ‘w3m−home−page’ is nil.\n\nThe variables ‘w3m−pop−up−windows’ and ‘w3m−pop−up−frames’ control
\nwhether this command should pop to a window or a frame up for the\nsession.\n\nWhen emacs−w3m s
essions have already been opened, this command will\npop to the existing window or frame up, but
if ‘w3m−quick−start’ is\nnil, (default t), you will be prompted for a URL (which defaults to\n‘po
pup’ meaning to pop to an existing emacs−w3m buffer up).\n\nIn addition, if the prefix argument i
s given or you enter the empty\nstring for the prompt, it will visit the home page specified by t
he\n‘w3m−home−page’ variable or the \"about:\" page.\n\nYou can also run this command in the batc
h mode as follows:\n\n emacs −f w3m http://emacs−w3m.namazu.org/ &\n\nIn that case, or if this c
ommand is called non−interactively, the\nvariables ‘w3m−pop−up−windows’ and ‘w3m−pop−up−frames’ w
ill be ignored\n(treated as nil) and it will run emacs−w3m at the current (or the\ninitial) windo
w.\n\nIf the optional NEW−SESSION is non−nil, this function makes a new\nemacs−w3m buffer. Besid
es that, it also makes a new emacs−w3m buffer\nif ‘w3m−make−new−session’ is non−nil and a user sp
ecifies a url string.\n\nThe optional INTERACTIVE−P is for the internal use; it is mainly used\nt
o check whether Emacs 22 or later calls this function as an\ninteractive command in the batch mod
e.\n\n(fn &optional URL NEW−SESSION INTERACTIVE−P)" t nil) w3m)
command−execute(w3m record)
execute−extended−command(nil "w3m") call−interactively(execute−extended−command nil nil) command−execute(execute−extended−command)
```

Comment: I am using it right now with emacs trunk, I dont have any problem with it.

Comment: I think there may be a problem with the make file for w3m on OSX from Github and from the CVS download and from emacs-w3m-1.4.4.tar.gz.  I have sent an e-mail to the mailing list for the package and their response seems to indicate an improperly configured byte compressed file.  I sure wish there were a way to bypass the make process and just download the built directory for OSX.  I'm using a developer build of Aquamacs post24.3/pre24.4, which should be roughly equivalent to the emacs trunk (except for spellcheck).  I can see, however, that the make process has errors when building emacs-w3m.

Comment: Okay, I got Github to install without an error.  I'm going to try emacs trunk next.

Comment: Nope, same thing with emacs-trunk.  I'll add the error message to the question.

Comment: Maybe errors/warnings during byte-compilation give you a hint.

Comment: That worked -- I turned off the `w3m-ems.elc.off` and `w3m.elc.off` so that only the corresponding `.el` files load, and MAGIC !!!!  Mailing list supporter `Katsumi Yamaoka` hit the nail on the head.  I'm looking forward to trying out this new decoding ability -- what wonderful way to start the day.  I'll work with them so that the byte compile error can be fixed for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or rename `w3m-ems.elc` and `w3m.elc` so that the corresponding `.el` files get loaded instead.  The byte compile errors that are now resolved (i.e., by removing the damaged files) occurred on OSX Mountain Lion when building emacs-w3m from Github:

```
git://github.com/emacsmirror/w3m.git
```

I also experienced various errors during the build process from source located at both of the following:

```
emacs-w3m-1.4.4.tar.gz at http://emacs-w3m.namazu.org/#download

cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@cvs.namazu.org:/storage/cvsroot co emacs-w3m
```

On an OSX box (Mountain Lion), the best result in my case was building from source located on Github and then removing the two damaged files.

With the help of two very talented people who are on the emacs-w3m mailing list (i.e., Tatsuya Kinoshita and Katsumi Yamaoka), they figured out that the byte compile error is caused because the build process requires a more recent version of emacs.  I was unaware that a version of emacs is used in the make byte-compile process.  There was an older version of emacs sitting in my /usr/bin that is referenced in the header of the byte-compiled file.  The solution would be to use a more recent version of emacs, which can be configured using `--with-emacs` path when building:

```
$ ./configure --with-emacs=/Path/to/your/preferred/Emacs
```

Now that the problem has been isolated, I have byte compiled new files to replace the bad ones.